# How to solve this scalar-Matrix minimization problem $\min_c \|A-cB\|^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to solve this minimization problem?

$L(\alpha )=\min_{\alpha}0.5\|A-\alpha B\|^2$
The derivative gives me $\alpha^2(A-\alpha B)$ which is weird since there is a solution for $\alpha=0$ which is wrong (for example if $A=0.9B$ then $\alpha=0.9$ is the correct solution)

I'm pretty sure it's straightforward and I blackout'ed (something with mean, median maybe?)...

One more: How about minimizing the Frobenius norm?

Comment: You should explain what norm you are referring to. The answer of mathreadler refers to the Frobenius norm, which is the one that treats matrices as if they were vectors, so to speak.

Comment: Yeah, I mis-typed this with the in my comment to his answer. (Unfortunatelly, I can't edit)

Answer (score 1):

First vectorize $A$ and $B$, let's call them $\bf a$ and $\bf b$, then we can change without loss of generality to this minimization :

$$\|\alpha{\bf b-a}\|_2^2 = (\alpha {\bf b-a})^T(\alpha \bf{b-a})$$

now we can expand and differentiate, set derivative to $0$ and solve and we can derive for example the normal equations:

$$\alpha = ({\bf b}^T{\bf b})^{-1}{{\bf b}^T{\bf a}}$$

This basically means $$\alpha = \frac{\text{(scalar product of b and a)}}{\text{(sum of squares of elements of b)}}$$

Comment: Cool! I just did not made the correct derivative T_T. How is the Forbinious norm different? I suppose is by scaling?

Comment: I think that this is specific of the Frobenius norm. If Natan meant another matrix norm, then I am not sure you can "vectorize", like you did here.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yep you are correct. The Frobenius norm will be minimized by vectorized 2 norm, but not all other norms will.